# Array of class and creating objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a class like this and need to create a collection of properties .in c# i can use a list or any collection type but how to do it in typescript .

```
class Movies implements Imovies{


    public Id : string;
    public get fid(): string {
        return this.Id;
    }
    public set fid(theid:string) {
        this.Id=theid;
    }

    public dailyrentalRate : number;
    public get fdailyrentalRate(): number {
        return this.dailyrentalRate;
    }
    public set fdailyrentalRate(theid:number) {
        this.dailyrentalRate=theid;
    }

    public numberinstock : number;
    public get fnumberinstock(): number {
        return this.numberinstock;
    }
    public set fnumberinstock(theid:number) {
        this.numberinstock=theid;
    }

    public publishDate : string;
    public get fpublishDate(): string {
        return this.publishDate;
    }
    public set fpublishDate(theid:string) {
        this.publishDate=theid;
    }

    public title : string;
    public get ftitle(): string {
        return this.title;
    }
    public set ftitle(theid:string) {
        this.title=theid;
    }
}
```

I  tried to insert values to array as follows

```
let mov=new Array<Movies>();

mov[0].fid="asdasd";
mov[0].fdailyrentalRate=2;
mov[0].fnumberinstock=5;
mov[0].fpublishDate="2018-05-23";
mov[0].ftitle="name";

mov[1].fid="asdasda";
mov[1].fdailyrentalRate=32;
mov[1].fnumberinstock=35;
mov[1].fpublishDate="2018-06-23";
mov[1].ftitle="name2";
```

but is showing an error

TypeError: Cannot set property 'fid' of undefined

Comment: `mov[0] = { fid: "asdasd", ... }`

Comment: thank you .it works.can i give something like this in typescript class

public string name{get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

you can also implement the class Movie using a constructor, and then create an array of Movie, like this:

```
const movies: Movie[] = [];
```

after you could push movie objects in the movies array:

```
const movie = new Movie();
movie.fid="test1"; 
movie.dailyrentalRate=2; 
movie.numberinstock=5; 
movie.publishDate="2018-05-23"; 
movie.title="name";     
movies.push(movie);
```

you can see a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-array-movies